# Laravel 5.4 Dynamic form save data to database

Tags: jquery, laravel-5.4

I am building a Point of Sale system for a pharmaceutical company. I am allowing the users to add more fields when a new stock is purchased and they want to add them to the existing ones. But I want to submit all of them at once no matter the number of fields they add. I am finding it difficult to do that in the controller.

This is my HTML

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 shad-content">
        <div class="panel-heading "><h3>Please add new drugs</h3></div>
            <div class="panel-body">
            <form action="{{ route('post-new-products') }}" method="POST">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <table id="add-me" class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Selling Price</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody >
                  <tr>
                    <td id="quantity" class="col-md-2"><input onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <=57' type="text" name="quantity[]" class="form-control" autofocus="" /></td>
                    <td class="col-md-7"><input type="text" name="description[]" class="form-control" /></td>
                    <td class="col-md-3"><input type="text" name="selling_price[]" class="form-control" /></td>
                    <td class="col-md-2">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
                        Delete</button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="action-buttons">
                <button id="add-form" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Add New Form</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save All Drugs</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>    
  </div>
 </div>
```

This is jQuery to add form dynamically

```
 $('#add-form').click(function() {
        i++;

        $('#add-me').append(
            '<tbody id="row'+i+'"><tr>'+

                '<td class="col-md-2">'+
                    '<input id="quantity" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <=57" type="text" name="quantity[]" class="form-control"/>'
                +'</td>'
                +'<td class="col-md-7">'
                    +'<input type="text" name="description[]" class="form-control"/>'
                +'</td>'
                +'<td class="col-md-3">'
                    +'<input type="text" name="selling_price[]" class="form-control" />'
                +'</td>'
                +'<td class="col-md-2">'
                    +'<button id="'+i+'" type="button" class="btn btn-danger delegated-btn">Delete</button>'
                +'</td>'


            +'</tr></tbody>'
            );

    });
```

This is my CONTROLLER

```
   public function createInventory(Request $request) {

        $product = new Product;
        $product->quantities = $request->get('quantity');
        $product->description = $request->get('description');
        $product->selling_price = $request->get('selling_price');
     $product->save();

}
```

And I keep getting this error `Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given, called in`

Comment: Any error in data saving ?

Comment: This is the error   `Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given, called in `

Comment: dont forget to also add `i` to the input names and ids. Can you dd($request)?

Comment: without `i` i get all the respective data without. but i dont know why it cant save

Comment: Can you post an example please? Both the html and controller